# How to crawl github info incrementally and deal with the info?

Tags: java, github-for-windows

I'm using java and GitHub API to crawl GitHub information in windows 7.

1. I'm wondering how can I know a project's info is updated.For example,when a new contributor joins a project,can GitHub informs me?Or should I crawl these info from time to time(like every X hours crawl).
2. Could you give me some advice about dealing with these data?I mean when a project's source code is updated(there's a commit changed original codes),should I just remove the original one and copy the new one into my computer and add an entry about this operation?

Comment: GitHub offers webhooks for a bunch of events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GitHub API Webhooks for getting notified about events. E.g. if you want to get notified when a new contributor joins the project you need to set up a Webhook for the following event :

> team_add  Any time a team is added or modified on a Repository.

There is also a wildcard event (*) that will match all the events. A good tutorial on how to set up and use Webhooks is available at [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/).

In terms of dealing with data, I guess it depends on what you are doing with the source code. E.g if you are going scan the code with some static analysis tool to look for bugs then you can just keep the new version of the code. Otherwise, if you are going to do some analytics on the entire commit history then you can keep track of all the modifications and changes.

Comment: Thank you so much!Your answer really helps me.Now I know where to focus on.

Comment: No worries, if you find the answer useful you can accept it.